# evaluate logical expression from string inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to rewrite a conditional operation purely using functions and introduce operators and arguments as variables.

for example something like 4>5 will be replaced with

```
import operator
arg1 = 4
arg2 = 5
result = operator.gt(arg1,arg2)
```

i would want to replicate the same for a complex expression that use multiple operators

for example in below case data is the input numbers will need to replaced with a function that can have values and operator supplied

```
data = {'val1':1,'val2':2,'val3':3,'val4':4,'val5':5,'val6':6}
exression_output = (data['val1'] > 0.5) & (data['val2'] == 2) & (data['val3'] >= 2)

what i did first is manually replace them like below
import operator
ops = {
    '+' : operator.add, '-' : operator.sub, '*' : operator.mul, '/' : operator.truediv,  # use operator.div for Python 2
    '%' : operator.mod, '^' : operator.xor, '<' : operator.lt, '<=' : operator.le,
    '==' : operator.eq, '!=' : operator.ne, '>' : operator.gt, '>=' : operator.ge,
    '&' :operator.and_
}
def eval_logical_operator(data,operations):
    if (len(operations)==1):
        return ops[operations[0]['operation']](data[operations[0]['op1']], operations[0]['op2'])
    if (len(operations)==2):
        return operator.and_(
                ops[operations[0]['operation']](data[operations[0]['op1']], operations[0]['op2']),
                ops[operations[1]['operation']](data[operations[1]['op1']], operations[1]['op2'])
                )
    if (len(operations)==3):
        return operator.and_(
                    operator.and_(
                        ops[operations[0]['operation']](data[operations[0]['op1']], operations[0]['op2']),
                        ops[operations[1]['operation']](data[operations[1]['op1']], operations[1]['op2'])
                    ),
                    ops[operations[2]['operation']](data[operations[2]['op1']], operations[2]['op2'])
        )
    #return new_df[operator.gt(op1, op2)]
    
eval_logical_operator(data,[{'op1':'val1','operation':'>','op2':0.5},])
eval_logical_operator(data,[
                            {'op1':'val1','operation':'>','op2':0.5},
                            {'op1':'val2','operation':'==','op2':2},
                            ]
                        )

eval_logical_operator(data,[
                            {'op1':'val1','operation':'>','op2':0.5},
                            {'op1':'val2','operation':'==','op2':2},
                            {'op1':'val3','operation':'>=','op2':2},
                            ]
                        )
```

to remove limitation of numbers of condition(if blocks) i replaced it with
below expression. it works, but can work only for And operations

```
def eval_expression(data, operations):
    output = []
    for exp in operations:
        expression_output = ops[exp['operation']](data[exp['op1']],exp['op2'])
        output.append(expression_output)
    
    return all(output)
        
eval_expression(data,[
                            {'op1':'val1','operation':'>','op2':0.5},
                            {'op1':'val2','operation':'==','op2':2},
                            {'op1':'val3','operation':'>=','op2':2},
                      ]
               )
```

this would fail if an 'or' is introduced like below
(data['val1'] > 0.5) & (data['val2'] == 2) | (data['val3'] >= 2)

can someone suggest a workaround this so that i can do this for a large complex expression like

```
data = {'val1':1,'val2':2,'val3':3,'val4':4,'val5':5,'val6':6}
output = (((data['val1'] > 0.5) & (data['val2'] == 2)) | (data['val3'] >= 2))&(data['val4'] >= 3)
```

i am willing to rewrite my input expression to accommodate this.

```
eval_logical_operator(data,[
                            {'op1':'val1','operation':'>','op2':0.5},
                            {'op1':'val2','operation':'==','op2':2},
                            {'op1':'val3','operation':'>=','op2':2},
                            ]
                        )
```

Comment: A much more elegant way of doing this would be to parse the abstract syntax tree and change all cmp operations to function calls of `operator`

Comment: could you give an example or links (about the concept)so that i can try this approach.

Comment: @rakesh Bitwise operators (such as `&`, `|`, `^`, etc) aren't the same as logical (i.e. boolean) operators. Thus: `bool(1 and 2)` => `True`, but `bool(1 & 2)` => `False`; and `(1 or 2) == (1 or 4)` => `True`, but `(1 | 2) == (1 | 4)` => `False`; etc. The operator module doesn't include the logical operators, because they short-circuit, which means their exact behaviour cannot be represented as functions. However, you might be able to use `all/any` instead of `and/or` for your particular use-case.

Comment: Oh sure thing, although a full implementation of this will be way too big to be posted as an answer on StackOverflow. I have included large parts of it with examples. @rakesh

Comment: This piqued my interest, I made an ast based converter here: https://github.com/Achxy/ConvertOperator relevant to the question, feel free to checkout :D

Answer (score 1):

This is how this problem could be approached with [Abstract Syntax Tree (AST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)

Firstly we will parse the python code into a tree, one standard implementation include ast in the python standard library (see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

Then we convert every `BinOp` Node to a `Call` node mapping from operations like `+`, `-` to `operator.add` and `operator.sub` for example. This can be done by subclassing `ast.NodeTrasnformer` then implementing `visit_BinOp` to return appropriate `Call` object.

This is an example of code a source to source compilation:

```py
from ast import (
    BinOp,
    Call,
    ImportFrom,
    Load,
    Module,
    Name,
    NodeTransformer,
    alias,
    fix_missing_locations,
    parse,
    unparse,
)
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Any

bin_op_special_cases = {
    "Mult": "mul",
    "Div": "truediv",
    "BitOr": "or_",
    "BitXor": "xor",
    "BitAnd": "and_",
    "MatMult": "matmul",
}


def _get_bin_conversion(op_name: str) -> str:
    return bin_op_special_cases.get(op_name, op_name.lower())


def _get_cls_name_of(obj: Any) -> str:
    cls = type(obj)
    return cls.__name__


class OperationNodeTransformer(NodeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, tree) -> None:
        self.operator_import_symbols = set()
        self.result = fix_missing_locations(self.visit(tree))

    def visit_BinOp(self, node: BinOp) -> Call:
        lhs, rhs = node.left, node.right
        op_name = _get_bin_conversion(_get_cls_name_of(node.op))
        self.operator_import_symbols.add(op_name)
        new_node = OperationNodeTransformer(
            Call(
                func=Name(id=op_name, ctx=Load()),
                args=[lhs, rhs],
                keywords=[],
            )
        )
        self.operator_import_symbols.update(new_node.operator_import_symbols)
        return new_node.result


def _is_ImportFromFuture(node) -> bool:
    return isinstance(node, ImportFrom) and node.module == "__future__"


def _add_ImportFromNode(
    mod: Module, mod_name: str, symbols: Iterable[str], level: int = 0
) -> None:
    node = ImportFrom(
        module=mod_name,
        names=[alias(name=name) for name in symbols],
        level=level,
    )
    body = mod.body
    first_expr = body[0]
    body.insert(int(_is_ImportFromFuture(first_expr)), node)


def convert_operations(py_code: str) -> str:
    tree: Module = parse(py_code)
    new = OperationNodeTransformer(tree)
    _add_ImportFromNode(new.result, "operator", new.operator_import_symbols)
    return unparse(new.result)


sample = """\
def foo(a, b):
    return a + b
"""

print(convert_operations(sample))

# Result :
# from operator import add

# def foo(a, b):
#     return add(a, b)
```

Now we can successfully convert python into new python code, although the above code has only been implemented for the following types :

```
class ast.Add
class ast.Sub
class ast.Mult
class ast.Div
class ast.FloorDiv
class ast.Mod
class ast.Pow
class ast.LShift
class ast.RShift
class ast.BitOr
class ast.BitXor
class ast.BitAnd
class ast.MatMult
```

(does not fully cover the `operator` alternatives, but the code is already way too big to be solitarily included in a single answer)

Example of a Fibonacci function being converted using `convert_operation` :
Old :

```py
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)


print(fib(5))
```

Converted :

```py
from operator import sub, add

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    return add(fib(sub(n, 1)), fib(sub(n, 2)))
print(fib(5))
```

(For `<=` to be converted, you'll have to implemented `ast.Compare` with `visit_Compare` which was too much to be included in this answer)

Hope that helps...